# need help calling functions from class

Tags: c++, class, function, object, if-statement

I'm having trouble picking the functions from `class OperateClass`

It asks the user "Do you want to add, subtract, multiply or divide? I want to :" (in main). No matter what I put, it goes to the function `int add`. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int x = 1;
int number;
int total = 0;
int amt = 1;
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
string ans;

class OperateClass{
    public:
        int add(){
            while(x <= 2){
                cout << "Enter a number to use to add: " << endl;
                    cin >> a;
                total = total + a;
                x++;
                amt++;
            }
        }

        int subtract(){
            while(x <= 2){
                cout << "Enter a number to use to add: " << endl;
                    cin >> b;
                total = total - b;
                x++;
                amt++;
            }
        }

        int multiply(){
            while(x <= 2){
                cout << "Enter a number to use to add: " << endl;
                    cin >> c;
                total = total * c;
                x++;
                amt++;
            }
        }

        int divide(){
            while(x <= 2){
                cout << "Enter a number to use to add: " << endl;
                    cin >> d;
                total = total / d;
                x++;
                amt++;
            }
        }
};

int main()
{

cout << "Do you want to add, subtract, multiply or divide? I want to : " << endl;
cin >> ans;

if(ans == "add"){
OperateClass opOper;
opOper.add();
    }

else if (ans == "subtract"){
    OperateClass opOper;
    opOper.subtract();
    }

else if (ans == "multiply"){
    OperateClass opOper;
    opOper.multiply();
    }

else if(ans == "divide"){
    OperateClass opOper;
    opOper.divide();

    }

}
```

also, is this below function good enough to print?

```
void print(){
    cout << "Your total is: " << total << endl;  Where should I call this?

}
```

Comment: How do you know the program always goes to add()?
Your functions have the same message to prompt "Enter a number to use to add: ". Have a different message for different function. like "Enter a number to divide".

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that. Also, I was wondering why when I enter in the numbers it prompts, it's not running the function void print();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the same text for all methods `"Enter a number to use to add: "`

Comment: Also, I was wondering why when I enter in the numbers it prompts, it's not running the function void print();

Comment: you have never called print(). so, if you want to print total after each calculation, call print() in each function after while loop.
OR in main(), after all if-else statements.

Comment: @LwinHtooKo Do I just add `void print()` after `amt++` in each while function?

Comment: @Bucky763 You just put print() at the last line of main().